# Possible way to clear the conversation state at the end of a conversation for Microsoft Teams

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm creating a bot and every time the conversation end, I'll to clear the conversation state. For That I'm sending an activity with type `endOfConversation` after the last message.

At the method `OnMessageActivityAsync` of my bot I've added this code.

```
turnContext.OnSendActivities(OnSendActivitiesHandlerAsync);
```

Witch must execute this code:

```
private async Task<ResourceResponse[]> OnSendActivitiesHandlerAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, List<Activity> activities, Func<Task<ResourceResponse[]>> next)
{
    foreach (Activity activity in activities)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.EndOfConversation)
        {
            await _conversationState.ClearStateAsync(turnContext); // <-- `_conversationState` is a global variable type of `BotState`.
        }
    }

    return await next();
}
```

It works very good in the Bot Framework Emulator, but when it goes live on Microsoft Teams I had errors. When looking for that message I've found this:

> That particular type is not supported in Teams, sorry.
>
> <sub>https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/3300</sub>

In the logs I see this when I want to send an `endOfConversation` type.

```
{
    "code": "BadArgument",
    "message": "Unknown activity type",
    "innerHttpError": null
}
```

I would to send an end of conversation type because based on that type I could clear the conversation state on the server side of the bot. In that state I store some objects that aren't not relevant anymore when the conversation is ended.

So my question is now how could I clear the conversation state at the end of an conversation without using the `endOfConversation` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"RichMoe" in the link you've provided states that Teams does not support this operation (2017) and I think the same is still true - I don't think Teams has a concept of the "end" of a conversation, in the way that, for example, a support bot on a website would - like any conversation, Teams will try to keep the entire chat history forever.

Perhaps you can explain why you need to "end" the conversation, if there's something related I can try help with.

Comment: if the conversation never actually "ends" in Teams, is it really correct to clear the conversation state? In theory the user could come back in the future and expect the bot to carry on from whatever point. If you really have short-lived items you could possibly use an alternate caching mechanism, and set an expiry date+time, just as an idea

Comment: A use case for this is a bot in the service desk or remote advisor scenario. There needs to be a way for the user to indicate they are done with this support session. In Skype for Business they would simply close the chat window.  Teams now has a popout /undock feature for 1-1 and meetings, but the close action here is just a redock and no event is sent to the remote party (bot).  We ended up implementing a inactivity timer on the bot end. Not an ideal situation but all that works in Teams for now.